# Using Angular inside of Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel and AngularJS for my project. I changed the Angular curly brackets to `{[{` because of, blade uses the same. I got some data with an `$http.post()` in AngularJS and I want to print this data in my views, witch I have made in Laravels blade. Because of, I am printing data from AngularJS I am using ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="school in data.result">
     <td><a href="{{ URL::to('scholen/bekijk/') }}">{[{ school.name }]}</a></td>
     <td>{[{ school.brin }]}</td>
     <td>{[{ school.city }]}</td>
     <td>{[{ school.phonenumber }]}</td>
</tr>
```

This works fine. The problem is: how can I print an value inside `{{ URL::to('scholen/bekijk/') }}`?

Something like:

```
{{ URL::to('scholen/bekijk/'. {[{ school.id}]}) }}
```

I tried a lot, but I got errors only ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something like:
>
> ```
> {{ URL::to('scholen/bekijk/'. {[{ school.id}]}) }}
> ```

### You can't.

Why? Blade is processed with PHP, which is server-side.

AngularJS processes client-side, once any/all Blade processing is completely finished.

Comment: Yes, I know. But blade creates my URL and I want to paste someting after it.

Comment: Why not just do `{{ URL::to('scholen/bekijk/') }}{[{ school.id }]}` then?

Comment: {{ URL::to('scholen/bekijk/'. {[{ school.id}]}) }} says: syntax error, unexpected '{'. But, you're right! I use {{ URL::to('scholen/bekijk/') }}/{[{ school.id }]} now ant is works.

Answer (score 1):

that is because

```
 {{ URL::to('scholen/bekijk/'. {[{ school.id}]}) }}
```

this code is interpret by php. but the syntax is incorrect acceding to php. because php accepts `{[{ school.id}]})` part as a interpret-able php thing but its not. if u can put `{[{ school.id}]})` inside the string then php is not going to interpret is because its know its just a `string`. but in angular side angular knows that's is a something that angular should do because the string includes `{[{ school.id}]})` .

so u can try something like,

```
{{ URL::to('scholen/bekijk/{[{ school.id}]})' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really pick one and stick with it, by that I mean don't try and mix Blade and Angular. If you want to go with Angular pages, then make them all Angular, not some kind of Blade-Angular hybrid.

When working with Angular and Laravel I completely remove any view logic from Laravel, and use it purely as the back-end logic. Angular is responsible for all the view templating and rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest don't mix angular and blade...

Look at this: https://github.com/Ferticidio/UPEnews/blob/master/app/views/indexangular.blade.php only load angular...

and: https://github.com/Ferticidio/UPEnews/tree/master/public
In public i push all the angular logic...

This was very fast and comprensive for me..